# How to set up reliable, cheap, always-on remotely administered pc

Tags: vnc, remote-access

I want to communicate back & forth with my dad in another state. He's practically deaf, blind in 1 eye, cannot type, and has no patience for keyboards of any size. He cannot use a mouse. His IQ is 140, can swim 2 miles, but he's 81. My idea was to set up a touch screen pc at his place and have him write when he feels like it, with his finger, on a Kolourpaint screen. I need to admin the remote pc 800 miles away, including restarting it if necessary. I will dedicate a pc at my house to a continuous rdesktop or tunneled VNC. Doable? If I can get wake-on-wan to work, how to best secure the remote pc? Any Linux distros especially suited for this?

Answer (score 2):

Luckily for you, for some reason the HTML5 ninjas decided that [whiteboard](http://unite.opera.com/application/491/) [collaboration](http://draw.2x.io/) [real](http://ide.cnu.se/diddly) [time](http://mugtug.com/sketchpad/) [drawing](https://cacoo.com/) [apps](http://www.idroo.com/) were cool and original.

(And yes, I just linked to 6 of them.)

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo Messenger.  Its free, has a built in whiteboard, and camera support.

Comment: Thanks, looks too complex for dad. And I need to max use of screen for him to write with a finger. It's looking like tightVNC or tigerVNC with Kolourpaint might work. (One instance for his board, one for mine). I don't think you can beat me at pool!

Comment: @klausnrooster: **Welcome to Super User!** Please note that comments aren't meant for chatting, but rather for comments that reflect the post. Feel free to create a room in [our chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com) if you want to start an interesting pool conversation...